# Check if one List<String> contains specific string from another list

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I have a `List<String> emails` containing emails, of length `n` , and another `List<String> keywords` for containing keywords, of the same length. These lists should meet following condition: For each index `i` `emails.get(i).contains(keywords.get(i))`

So, if `emails.get(0) == "quick brown fox"`, then `keywords.get(0) == "fox"`.

if `emails.get(5) == "foo bar"`, then `keywords.get(5) == "foo"`.

How can I check (other than `for` loop) that each email contains a keyword?

Comment: What do you mean by `order is important`?

Comment: You must have a for loop. Looking for `contains()` (which has the for loop)?

Comment: First email should contain first keyword, and so on, last email should contain last keyword

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for-loop?

Comment: @MorganS42 
`for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++) {
            strings.get(i).contains(substrings.get(i));
        }`
I wrote it like this, I am wondering if it can be done functional style

Comment: Understood, you can use it with Java 8's streams, I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: @RafalLovesWorking do you want it to just return a boolean for whether all the emails contain their respective keyword, or do you want it to return what emails are missing their keyword?

Comment: @MorganS42 I want it to return boolean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it may be needed to check the size of both lists, then to compare corresponding list items, `IntStream` should be used:

```java
public static boolean allKeywordsFound(List<String> emails, List<String> keywords) {
    return emails.size() == keywords.size() &&
        IntStream.range(0, emails.size())
            .allMatch(i -> emails.get(i).contains(keywords.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see that others correctly answered your question but here's my take on the issue.
I presume you want the emails to be checked in order so here's a piece of code that uses `Stream API` instead of a `for` loop, I also put together the emails list and the result into a `Map` since you didn't specify whether you want the resulting `boolean` value to be for all the emails together or if you want a boolean value for each email containing the same-position keyword:

```
//mock data initialization
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();

//mock data initialization
emails.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua");
emails.add("eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis");
emails.add("Dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris");

//mock data initialization
keywords.add("consectetur");
keywords.add("Foo");
keywords.add("Dignissim");

//initialized a list to contain whether a keyword exists for each email
List<Boolean> exists = new ArrayList<>();

//loaded it with boolean values (the exists List has the same order as the emails list)
emails.forEach(email -> exists.add(email
            .contains(keywords
                    .get(emails
                            .indexOf(email)))));

//since I don't know what you wanna do with the result, I decided to just put them together in a Map
//with the email string as the key and the existence variable as a value
LinkedHashMap mapOfTruth = new LinkedHashMap();
emails.forEach(email -> mapOfTruth.put(email, exists.get(emails.indexOf(email))));
```

**Output**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua = true
eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis = false
Dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris = true
```

Comment: `forEach(Consumer)` is part of the `Iterable` interface and the default implementation is also just using a normal for-loop which calls the `Consumer`s `accept` method in each iteration. I'm not saying your version is better or worse, but it is very close to a traditional loop and is not part of the `Stream API`.